# PHP - how to execute ajax method via cron tab in Curl?

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I want to know how do I make my ajax request run in crontab?
I have here an ajax request that gets data from an api, for each data I'm executing ajax post request to update a row in my database.

How do I do this in Curl?

here is my script,

```
function getDataFs()
{
    var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://url/api/employees', 
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(response){  
            console.log(response);
            for(i=0; i < response.length; i++)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/update_employees_list',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { 'employee_data': response[i], '_token': _token },
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                })
            }   
        }
    });     
}
```

I'm also passing request headers and xhr fields,

I hope someone can help me with this, If not possible on ajax , can you help me accomplish this on Curl or any possible solution for this,
Thank You!

Comment: check my answer, its like prototype for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like following and add this file in the Crontab.

```
//getting all initial response
$raw_response = doCurl('https://url/api/employees', false, 'GET');
$response = json_decode($raw_response);

//iterate them
foreach ($response as $value) {
    //set your headers
    $headers = array();
    //set your post data
    $post_arr = array();
    //make your sub requests.
    doCurl($url, $headers, 'POST', $post_arr);
}


function doCurl($url, $headers, $method = 'GET', $post_arr = array()){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

    if ($method === 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_arr);
    }

    if (!empty($headers)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a technology that works only in your browser, but it is based on regular HTTP requests. Using the Firefox developer console, you can simply copy an executed AJAX request to a cURL call. This can be used in your cronjob

Comment: can you show me a demo or a working sample for that, Im still confused, can you show me a link or a draft, thank you!